# How to boot from DVD/USB on Windows 8. Where is the boot priority menu?

Tags: windows-8, boot, usb, bios

I am trying to boot a Linux Live CD on my windows 8 system. I want to boot it live then install it to an external hard drive to also boot from later/at will.

I have found the option under Settings to boot into the BIOS through advanced startup. When I enter into the BIOS this way it gives me no options for booting from USB, DVD, or any device for that matter.

Does anyone know a solution, where I can find the boot device options,  or how I can make my system boot from these two devices? Thanks.

EDIT: If it's helpful here is the info

BaseBoardManufactuer is Samsung,
BaseBoardProduct is DP500A2D-K01UB,
BIOSVendor is American Megatrends,

Comment: What kind of BIOS do you have? Can you post screen shots (from your camera)? Is there a manual somewhere on the internet we can take a look at?

Comment: I apologize I do not have the ability to do that nor do I know what type of BIOS I have. Windows 7 and and prior all I had to do was press a key during boot to enter into the boot menu and select my device. Have they done away with this completely? I assumed there was an easy solution.

Comment: This is not a feature by Windows but by your BIOS which is usually described in detail in the manual of the mainboard. Do you know the type and manufacturer of the mainboard?

Comment: No sorry It's a Samsung All-In-One Desktop.

Comment: Then maybe in the computer manual. If you don't have one on paper, there might be one on the internet.

Comment: BaseBoardManufactuer is Samsung BaseBoardProduct is DP500A2D-K01UB BIOSVendor is American Megatrends. As per my registry info.

Answer (score 1):

AMI usually offers such a feature in their BIOS, if the manufacturer (Samsung) didn't strip it away.

You should be able to change your boot device setting in BIOS, which you can access by pressing DEL, F2, Alt+F2, ESC, or F12 (depending on your specific BIOS) a few seconds after starting your machine.

In the BIOS look through the menus for a related setting to change.

Comment: Just tried it. Didn't work. 

I can get into the BIOS by restarting in Advanced Starup mode. There are no options in the Boot section part though. it says press the arrow keys to chose a device but there are no devices. Has 1 option on the list. Just says boot manager.

Comment: Try with **Esc**. Samsung laptops and desktops usually use **Esc** rather than **F12** for a boot menu

Comment: This also did not work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to:

- make sure the USB drive was in formatted FAT32
- plug the USB drive before (re)starting the PC

After that, the BIOS started showing the USB option in the boot priorities. I was then able to boot from my USB drive and install my new OS.